# Transferring Data Between Tables with Word VBA?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have document containing all the questions in a certain test along with a table of its statistics. I'm attempting to transfer data between these tables, specifically inserting the percentage of people who chose a certain multiple choice answer into a box beside the actual answer in the question.

I've attached a screenshot of what the question table and statistic table look like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3fBy.png), there are 25 question tables in my document and one statistics table that goes on for 25 question.

Below is my code. The portion under the Else condition is functional but I can't seem to get my first If Condition and loop to collect the data from the statistics table into the array I set up. Hopefully someone can provide insight into why the first section is not working.

```
Sub Insert_Statistics()

Dim QTable As Table
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim StringValue As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim A(35) As String
Dim B(35) As String
Dim C(35) As String
Dim D(35) As String

For Each QTable In ActiveDocument.Tables


If RowCount > 14 Then


Do While i < 25


A(i + 1) = QTable.Rows(4 * i + 4).Cells(4).Range.Text
B(i + 1) = QTable.Rows(4 * i + 4).Cells(5).Range.Text
C(i + 1) = QTable.Rows(4 * i + 4).Cells(6).Range.Text
D(i + 1) = QTable.Rows(4 * i + 4).Cells(7).Range.Text

i = i + 1


Loop


Else


QTable.Rows(1).Cells(2).Select
StringValue = Selection.Text
j = Val(StringValue)

QTable.Rows(6).Cells(3).Range.Text = A(j)
QTable.Rows(6).Cells(3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
QTable.Rows(7).Cells(3).Range.Text = B(j)
QTable.Rows(7).Cells(3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
QTable.Rows(8).Cells(3).Range.Text = C(j)
QTable.Rows(8).Cells(3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
QTable.Rows(9).Cells(3).Range.Text = D(j)
QTable.Rows(9).Cells(3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft


QTable.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow

End If

Next



End Sub
```

Comment: that's because row count has no value assigned to it, so the condition If RowCount > 14 Then is never met and you always reach the else condition

Comment: Thank you for the input, that was my mistake. However, when I added RowCount = QTable.Rows.Count to define the variable, it still did not work (It was there in my original code but I tried writing a new one from scratch after running into problems, hence why I forgot it in the version that I posted for help)

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the first If Condition, specifically the loop, the array is not collecting any information from the Statistics Table so I'm wondering if there is an error with my formatting or my entire procedure to tackle this problem

Comment: Thankfully a friend pointed out to me that for my code to work, the statistics table had to be placed before all the questions so that the If condition containing the array would be met first and it would collect the statistics then place them into the question table afterwards. Thank you again for your input